# Cannot Spawn basic figures in Unity via in game menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I was tasked with a project from my boss to create a basic scene with primitive objects and one unique object. I created the objects as well as the first person camera/ character etc. Te only thing that is wrong is that every time I run the script and launch the game, every time I click on the menu toggle button, all the forms that are needed to be placed, keep spawning infinitely wherever the player is looking at. What I want is for the player to toggle the menu, click on the choices, after he clicks, the object appears (a single object) and the player can place it anywhere in the scene.

Here is the C# code from unity. I think it is the code for the spawn is what keeps looping but I want it to stop looping.

```
public class menuScript : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject[] items;
private itemplacement itemPlacement;
private bool menuWindowToggle = false;
private Rect menuWindowRect = new Rect(300,100,400,400);

private Dictionary<int,string> inventoryNameDictionary;

// icons
public Texture2D cubeIcon;
public Texture2D columnIcon;
public Texture2D sphereIcon;
public Texture2D robotIcon;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    itemPlacement = GetComponent<itemplacement> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
void OnGUI()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <items.Length; i ++) {
        menuWindowToggle = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (800, 50, 100, 50), menuWindowToggle, "Item Menu");
        if (menuWindowToggle) {
            menuWindowRect = GUI.Window (0, menuWindowRect, menuWindowMethod, "Item Menu");

            itemPlacement.SetItem (items [i]);
        }
    }
}
void menuWindowMethod (int windowId)
{
    Dictionary<int,string> inventoryNameDictionary = new Dictionary<int,string> ()
    {
        {0, string.Empty},
        {1, string.Empty},
        {2, string.Empty},
        {3, string.Empty}
    };

    itemClass cube = new itemClass (0, "Cube", cubeIcon, "Top of the line IKEA CUBE, made to break easily");
    itemClass column = new itemClass (1, "Column", columnIcon, "Best Persian Column in world, no need paint, it perfect!!!");
    itemClass sphere = new itemClass (2, "Sphere", sphereIcon, "ITS SPHERICAL.... SPHERICAL!!!");
    itemClass robot = new itemClass (3, "Robot", robotIcon, "Mysterious thing, comes from emails about projects");
    //display inventory
    inventoryNameDictionary [0] = cube.name;
    inventoryNameDictionary [1] = column.name;
    inventoryNameDictionary [2] = sphere.name;
    inventoryNameDictionary [3] = robot.name;

    GUILayout.BeginArea (new Rect (5, 50, 395, 400));
    GUILayout.BeginVertical ();
    GUILayout.Button (inventoryNameDictionary[0], GUILayout.Height (50));
    GUILayout.Button (inventoryNameDictionary[1], GUILayout.Height (50));
    GUILayout.Button (inventoryNameDictionary[2], GUILayout.Height (50));
    GUILayout.Button (inventoryNameDictionary[3], GUILayout.Height (50));
    GUILayout.EndVertical ();
    GUILayout.EndArea ();
}
public class itemClass
{
    public int item;
    public string name;
    public Texture2D icon;
    public string description;

    public itemClass( int ide, string nam, Texture2D ico, string des)
    {
        item = ide;
        name = nam;
        icon = ico;
        description = des;
    }
}
```

}

The other code that is in charge of placing is:

```
public class itemplacement : MonoBehaviour {
private Transform currentItem;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (currentItem = null) {
        Vector3 m = Input.mousePosition;
        m = new Vector3(m.x,m.y,transform.position.y);
        Vector3 p = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(m);
        currentItem.position = new Vector3(p.x,0,p.z);
    }
}
public void SetItem(GameObject b){
    currentItem = ((GameObject)Instantiate(b)).transform;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually familiar with the old GUI stuff (Unity doesn't recommend using it anymore apparently), so I looked it up here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gui-Basics.html

My understanding of the code you've posted is that GUI.Window() draws your window, using menuWindowMethod() to draw the contents, but this only *draws* the window. It does not wait for the user to do something inside of it. So as you've written the code here, execution will continue on immediately to the SetItem call.

Since OnGUI gets called every frame, and the Toggle control always returns its current value, the moment you toggle it on you'll be running that loop and calling SetItem once for every item in items for every frame.

I suspect what you really want to be doing is to wire up those buttons to set a new currentItem on your itemplacement component when they get clicked, and then wait until the user clicks again to call SetItem. I don't think you actually want that for loop in the OnGUI function.

Comment: Correct, I wish to have it to where each button the user clicks on generates the specified game object and it allows them to place it anywhere they want on the terrain.How do I do that with this code?